# Question in a proof from Gathmann's notes on Algebraic Geometry: The tangent space.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, localization, local-rings, tangent-bundle

I am studying chapter 10 from Gathmann's notes about algebraic geometry and there is something I don't understand in the following proof.

[image]

I don't really understand the equality $\frac{g}{f} = c g$. If I understand well, the aim of this part is to show that $S^{-1}(I(a)/I(a)^2) \subseteq I(a)/ I(a)^2$ so that we can deduce the ismorphism since the other inclusion is trivial. So this equality has to be understood as an equality in $S^{-1}(I(a)/I(a)^2)$, i.e.
$$\frac{g}{f} = \frac{cg}{1} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \exists t \in S, ~t(g - cf g) = 0 \text{ in }A(X).$$
But I really don't see how we deduce from the first part that $\exists t \in S, ~t(g - cf g) = 0 $ since $f$ is invertible in $A(X)/I(a)$, not in $A(X)$. Any help ?

Comment: $t(g-cfg)=0$ for some $t$ should be due to the localization. So you might want to check the definition/construction. But do not take my word for it.

Comment: I don't really understand, the construction of the localization ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take two arbitrary elements $f\in A(X)/I(a)$ and $g\in I(a)/I(a)^2$. Then, by abuse of notation also denoting some representative of $f$ and $g$ by $f$ and $g$ respectively, we have

$$(f+I(a))(g+I(a)^2) = fg + \underbrace{fI(a)^2}_{\in I(a)^2} + \underbrace{gI(a)}_{\in I(a)^2} + I(a)^3 = fg + I(a)^2, $$

and hence $fg \in I(a)/I(a)^2$ (in the above calculation, read '+I(a)' as 'there is an element in $I(a)$ s.t. the equation holds' and analogously for higher powers).

It is clear that $\frac{1}{f} = c$ in $A(X)/I(a)$. Then by the above argumentation,

$$g\frac{1}{f} = \frac{g}{f} = cg \in I(a)/I(a)^2.$$

The argument this is that if we would localize $I(a)/I(a)^2$ at $S$, the only new elements would be of the form $\frac{g}{f}$ with $f\in S$, but we just showed that they already lay in $I(a)/I(a)^2$, so that localization does not add any new elements.

Comment: Why is $I(a)/I(a)^2$ an ideal in $A(X)/I(a)$? Since $A(X)/I(a)$ is a field, it as no proper ideal right ?

Comment: @Falcon Yes I suppose that is a little odd. Thinking about it, one does only need the ideal property of $I(a)$ in $A(X)$ to make sure that $cg$ is indeed in $I(a)/I(a)^2$, I will edit the answer so that it is stated more clearly.

Comment: I am really sorry but there is still something that I don't understand. The fact that $I(a)/I(a)^2$ has to be stable under the multiplication by an element $\bar{f}$ of $A(X)/I(a)$ is intuitive because $I(a)/I(a)^2$ is stable for the multiplication by $K$. But the thing that bothers me is that I don't understand why $1/\bar{f}g$ has to be the same as $g/f$ because still $f \in S$. How can we see that for $\pi: I(a)/I(a)^2 \to S^{-1}I(a)/I(a)^2$, $\pi(1/\bar{f}g) = g/f$ ?

Comment: Suppose you have some ring $R$, a prime ideal $I$ and an invertible element $f\in S = R\backslash I$ with inverse $f^{-1}$. Then $\frac{1}{f} \sim \frac{f^{-1}}{1}$ in $S^{-1}R$, since $1 - f f^{-1} = 0$ in $R$.

Comment: But the element $f \in S$ is not really invertible in $R$, its projection $\bar{f}$ is

Comment: The way we use localization here is localization of an $R$-module $M$ at a multiplicative subset $S$ of $R$. $I(a)/I(a)^2$ is an $A(x)$-module by $f\cdot \bar{g} = \overline{fg}$. If $\overline{f}^{-1}$ is the inverse of $\overline{f}$ in $A(x)/I(a)$, then $\overline{g\cdot f^{-1}} \in I(a)/I(a)^2$ for all $g\in I(a)/I(a)^2$ as before, and $\frac{\overline{gf^{-1}}}{1} \sim \frac{g}{f}$ in the localization, since $f\cdot (\overline{gf^{-1}}) = \overline{fgf^{-1}} = g$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative proof when $A$ is a regular ring: Let $k\rightarrow A$ be a $k$-algebra with $k$ a field and let $\Omega^1_{A/k}:=I/I^2$ with $I \subseteq A\otimes_k A$ the kernel of the multiplication map. Let $\mathfrak{m}\subseteq A$ be a $k$-rational point. It follows $A_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}_{\mathfrak{m}}\cong A/\mathfrak{m}:=\kappa(x)$ where $x$ is the point corresponding to $\mathfrak{m}$. Let $X:=Spec(A)$. By definition
$T_X=Hom_A(\Omega^1_{A/k}, A)$ is the "tangent module" of $X$. The sheafification $\tilde{T_X}:=\Theta_X$ is the tangent sheaf of $X$, and the fiber $\Theta_{X,x} \otimes _{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} \kappa(x)$ is by definition the tangent space at the point $x$. If $A$ is a finitely generated and regular ring over $k$ it follows $\Theta_X$ is locally free of finite rank and
you get

$$\Theta_{X,x} \otimes _{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} \kappa(x) \cong Hom_{\kappa(x)}(\Omega^1_{A/k}\otimes \kappa(m), \kappa(x))  \cong Hom_{\kappa(x)}(I/I^2\otimes \kappa(x), \kappa(x))$$

and

$$I/I^2\otimes \kappa(x) \cong \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$$

hence

$$\Theta_{X,x}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} \kappa(x) \cong (\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)^*.$$

Hence the vector spaces $(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)^*$
"patch together" to form a locally trivial finite rank sheaf - the tangent sheaf of $X$.

Comment: Claiming that you can pull $\kappa(x)$ inside the Hom requires justification: it is not true in general that $\operatorname{Hom}_A(L,M)\otimes_A B \cong \operatorname{Hom}_B(L\otimes_A B,M\otimes_A B)$. ($A=M=\Bbb Z$, $L=B=\Bbb Q$, for instance.)